# How to set parameters with no data value in Apache IoTDB to speed up query time using sum?

Tags: sum, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I just finished setting up Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1 and I frequently need to use "sum" command to calculate data. I am now using aligned time series, so I want to ask how should I store the parameter in one time series with no data value. Should I set these parameter to null or 0 to attain lower query time consuming when doing "sum" calculation?